# Looking for a short story/graphic novel with ghosts and machines

Tags: identification-request

I read this graphic novel about four to five years ago.

It has traveling between worlds, I think. Maybe the ghost and the human world? But I don't know - I do know that the character met his grandfather and can fly. There's a lot of other magic, like changing sizes and maybe teleportation.

A bunch of other random facts from the story:

- They ate spiders.
- The characters in the (maybe) ghost world aren't really human.
- Time/world travel ship created by a women.
- The people sent to fetch the main character were in a relationship.
- There was an evil dude who used this weird machine that produced green light to determine the main character's potential.

Is there any fantasy graphic novel that fits this description?

Comment: Also the question and answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/270339/looking-for-weird-fantasy-graphic-novel

Comment: @SeanDuggan I asked the question in two different stack exchange sites in hopes that someone in one of the two sites could answer me.

Comment: I get that. I did the same with an old fantasy computer game, posting it in both SF&F and Retrocomputing. I just figured it was worth mentioning here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ghostopolis by Doug TenNapel perhaps.

Description from [goodreads.com](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7293595-ghostopolis):

> A page-turning adventure of a boy's journey to the land of ghosts and
> back.
>
> Imagine Garth Hale's surprise when he's accidentally zapped to the
> spirit world by Frank Gallows, a washed-out ghost wrangler. Suddenly
> Garth finds he has powers the ghosts don't have, and he's stuck in a
> world run by the evil ruler of Ghostopolis, who would use Garth's
> newfound abilities to rule the ghostly kingdom. When Garth meets
> Cecil, his grandfather's ghost, the two search for a way to get Garth
> back home, and nearly lose hope until Frank Gallows shows up to fix
> his mistake.